# Cylinder as Fibre bundles

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I have to show that the cylinder C is a fibre bundle over $S^1$ with fibre an open interval and I have to write a trivialization and the cocycles.
I think that this is a trivial bundle, because I can see it as $S^1 \times (a,b)$ (how I can argue this better?). In this trivial case, a trivilization is given only by the identity and the cocycle is trivially the identity too. Is what i wrote right? Thanks.

Comment: For starters, do you know how to write down coordinate charts for the circle...?